# Lambda expression to get a list of properties from a List<BaseClass> when the property is defined in a DerivedClass

Tags: c#, lambda, covariance

I am writing code to exchange information between different applications. All the applications define the same entities, but not all store the same information.

All applications define the class Animal, but:

- ApplcationA specifies: Genus, Species, Geographic distribution
- ApplcationB specifies: Genus, Species, Estimated population

I have an independent dll application (MyApplication.dll) where I have defined a class MyAnimal with the common information:

```
public class MyAnimal
{
   public string Genus { get; set; }
   public string Species { get; set; }
}
```

and a class MyAnimals containing a list of animals

```
public class MyAnimals
{
   public List<MyAnimal> ListOfAnimals { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationA and ApplicationB provide dlls to access their information. But the only way to do it is creating a plugin and executing it within the application themselves.

For ApplicationA have created the following classes

```
public class AppMyAnimal : MyAnimal
{
   public Animal SourceAnimal { get; set; } // the animal as defined by ApplicationA
   public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

   public AppMyAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
      // Set properties of Derived class
      SourceAnimal = animal;

      // Set properties of Base class
      Genus = animal.Genus;
      Species = animal.Species;
   }
}

public class AppMyAnimals : MyAnimals
{
   public AppMyAnimals()
   {
      ListOfAnimals = new List<MyAnimal>(); // List of animals of Base class MyAnimal; not of Derived class AppMyAnimal
   }
}
```

Within ApplicationA I have a function that populates the list of animals in AppMyAnimals class:

```
  private void ReadAnimals()
  {
     AppMyAnimals my_animals = new AppMyAnimals();
     List<Animal> list_of_animals = ClassInApplicationA.GetAnimals(); // list of animals as defined by ApplicationA
     foreach (Animal i_animal in list_of_animals)
     {
        AppMyAnimal app_my_animal = new AppMyAnimal(i_animal);
        my_animals.ListOfAnimals.Add(app_my_animal); // ok to assing Derived type to Base type (covariance)
     }
  }
```

I have a Form to select animals. The selected animals will have the IsSelected property in AppMyAnimal set to true.

I can serialize AppMyAnimals and AppMyAnimal as MyAnimals and MyAnimal to pass the information to ApplicationB.

But while in ApplicationA I would like to get a list of the selected animals, but of class Animal (as defined by ApplicationA):

```
List<Animal> list_of_selected_animals = ...
```

My first question is how to do it using a Lambda expression. The second question is if it there is a better set up for this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Don't you just need to grab the source animal? E.g. `List<Animal> list_of_selected_animals = my_animals.Select( x => x.SourceAnimal) ).ToList()`

Comment: I have ```List<MyAnimal>``` and I need ```List<Animal>``` when ```IsSelected``` is true. The object ```MyAnimal``` and the property ```IsSelected``` are in class ```AppMyAnimal```.

Answer (score 0):

> I have `List<MyAnimal>` and I need `List<Animal>` when `IsSelected` is true. The object `MyAnimal` and the property `IsSelected` are in in class `AppMyAnimal`

```
var listOfMyAnimal = new List<MyAnimal>();
var listOfSelectedAnimal = listOfMyAnimal
    .Where( x => x.IsSelected )
    .Select( x => x.SourceAnimal )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Without ```.Cast<AppMyAnimals>()``` the following message is displayed: 'MyAnimal' does not contain a definition for 'IsSelected' and no extension method 'IsSelected' accepting a first argument of type 'MyAnimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) –